# Plextor S2C very slow performance

Tags: ssd

New Plextor S2C (512 GB) works very slowly.
Is it a problem with my instance or Plextor deceives with the claimed characteristics?

[image]

[image]

**SSD has last firmware.**
Plextool shows same result:

And one more thing, why plextool shows PCIe, but my disk has SATA interface?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. 
Problem in slow controller Marvel 91xx
Afeter connect disk to Intel C600 controller, speed has become close to the declared.
[image]

Besided plextool now show right interface:
[image]